# 1cfresh api - создание и получение данных

Tags: api, 1с

Столкнулся с необходимостью поработать с облачной версией 1С (1cfresh).
Нужно через api создавать счета, получать контрагентов, сгенерированные документы для печати и получать поступления.
Основная проблема в документации. Она вроде бы есть, но переварить её выходит с большим трудом.
Удалось получить контрагентов через oData. Но счета таким образом не возвращаются (ошибка Сегмент пути ОсновнойБанковскийСчет не найден!). Так же через oData не добавляются данные (ошибка 403 Forbidden)

Возможно у кого-то есть опыт взаимодействия с этим продуктом или примеры кода, или адекватная документация. Буду крайне признателен за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oData. Проблема была в том, что связи у объектов нужно подтягивать с помощью `$expand=`, т.е. что бы получить любую сущность нужно составить подобный запрос:
`//odata/standard.odata/Catalog_Валюты?$expand=*&$select=*`

В ответ вернется сущность со всеми связями.

Сюда же ограничение на изменение данных. Для 1c fresh oData работает только в режиме чтения.

Что бы что-то изменить необходимо использовать механизм интеграции объектов, который работает через механизм DataTransfer.

В целом вот неплохой пример на питоне из документации:
https://its.1c.ru/db/fresh#content:25756595:hdoc

В чем суть, вкратце:

- нужно сгенерировать документ в соответствии с одним из форматов (EnterpriseData, DirectBank, 1CClientBankExchange)
- упаковать этот документ в zip архив, добавив к нему манифест
- инициировать сессию DataTransfer
- выгрузить файл
- дождаться его обработки на стороне 1С

Еще из полезного:

Описание формата EnterpriseData: https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:5934:hdoc

Документация по oData: https://its.1c.ru/db/v8319doc#bookmark:dev:TI000001358

Надеюсь, кому-то это поможет